# xmlStreamReader Evaluation Error: Wrapped java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: demandware

During debugging my DW script, When I debug xmlStreamReader I have tried to look for .hasNext() which will give me TRUE
but getting .next() will terminate the script, thus
I am not able to continue from .next() point after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced the same problem, I have made the hasNext as Number variable.

The issue is with this -> orderXMLReader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT

Here orderXMLReader.next() return String value and it is compared with Number constant